# how set curren_user_admin.id in model Post ??? I'm using ActiveAdmin + Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin + Cancan, i have this models

- AdmiUser
- Notice

I want set the **id** of the current_user_admin in Notice model before save a notice

```
class Notice < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :admin_user
   belongs_to :category

   before_save :set_admin_user_id

   def set_admin_user_id
      self.admin_user_id = ?   # maybe..! : current_admin_user.id 
   end
   ...
end
```

here is the link on github [activeadmin-cancan-roles](https://github.com/jardix22/activeadmin-cancan-roles/blob/master/app/models/notice.rb) 
I don't know ..!!! :(

Answer (score 2):

You don't! Doing so would violate the principles of Model-View-Controller. Only the controller should know about the current user.

If you need to store the current admin user in a `Notice` instance, then just set it when you create it (which you're doing in the controller anyway, where you have access to who the current admin user is).